# Im having an issue with this error running function `onTick`: [string "?"]:66: attempt to compare number with nil

Tags: lua

Im worrking on a script in stormworks. Im not sure why i am getting this error. error running function `onTick`: [string "?"]:66: attempt to compare number with nil

````
function onTick()
   --Number Inputs
   bOPSet = input.getNumber(1) --Pressure Blow Off Pressure Number Set
   bOTSet = input.getNumber(2) --Boiler Over Temp Number Set
   cOTSet = input.getNumber(3) --Core Over Temp Number Set
   cOPTSet = input.getNumber(14) --Core Operating Temp Set

   coreTemp = input.getNumber(4) --Core Temp
   b1T = input.getNumber(6) --Boiler 1 Temp
   b1P = input.getNumber(5) --Boiler 1 Pressure
   b2T = input.getNumber(7) --Boiler 2 Temp
   b2P = input.getNumber(8) --Boiler 2 Pressure
   genMTank = input.getNumber(9)
   condTank = input.getNumber(10)
   g1 = input.getNumber(11) --Generator 1 Output
   g2 = input.getNumber(12) --Generator 2 Output
   cRI = input.getNumber(13) --Current Control Rod Insertion

   --Bool Inputs
   sysStart = input.getBool(1) --System Start Switch

   --Number Outputs
   output.setNumber(1,coreIns) --Core Assembly Track
   output.setNumber(2,cRT) --Control Rod Insertion Target
   output.setNumber(3,gOutput) --Total Generator Output

   --Bool Outputs
   output.setBool(1,mAux) --Main Aux
   output.setBool(5,cTPump) --Condensation Transfer Pump
   output.setBool(6,bOV) --Pressure Blow Off Valve
   output.setBool(7,nClock) --Nuclear Core Lock
   output.setBool(8,cOTInd) --Core Overtemp Indicator

   --Add Generator Output
   gOutput = g1 + g2


   --Start main pumps, coolers, and lights. Insert Fuel Assembly
   if sysStart == true
       then coreIns = 1
           mAux = true
       else  coreIns = -1
           mAux = false
   end

   --Reactor Operation
   if coreTemp < cOTSet and coreTemp < cOPTSet  and cOTInd == false
       then cRT = coreTemp / cOPTSet
   end

   --Reactor Overtemp Protocol
   if coreTemp < cOTSet
       then cRT = 1
           nClock = true
           coreIns = -2
           cOTInd = true
   end

   --Condenser Tank Flow
   if condTank > 1
       then cTPump = true
       else cTPump = false
   end

   --Pressure Blow Off Valve
   if boiler1Press > bOPSet or boiler2Press > bOPSet
       then bOV = true
       else bOV = false
   end
end```
````

Comment: which part of the error message was not clear? if you want to compare two number values in line 66 and Lua complains about you attempting to compare a number and a nil value i line 66, it should be obvious that one of the number values you wanted to compare is not a number but a nil value. so ask yourself which of both and why. check where you assigned a number to that variable using text search...

Answer (score 0):

`boiler1Press` and `boiler2Press` are `nil` because you named them something else

```lua
   if b1P > bOPSet or b2P > bOPSet
       then bOV = true
       else bOV = false
   end
```